# jsfiddle keyboard shortcut to "run" code

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, jsfiddle

I often have to click the "run" button on jsfiddle to run my code. Is there a keyboard shortcut to run code on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/).

And yes, it seems there are some keyboard shortcuts -- see the *"Keyboard shortcuts"* link at the bottom left of the page ;-)

And here is the window that pops up when you click that link :

[image]
<sub>(source: [pascal-martin.fr](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/so-6833741.png))</sub>

Comment: It's no longer there?

Comment: I agree.  The keyboard shortcut help is no longer there.  Some of the keystrokes shown in the screenshot above no longer work, either.  ^Return (^Enter) works to run the fiddle, but toggling the sidebar does not.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid in any way. Please update

Answer (score 11):

`Ctrl + Enter` is the shortcut to run code.